# How to Stream a camera view from another computer on Discord with better performance?

Tags: video, performance, redirection, editing, obs-studio

For some issues with the app Discord, my client told me he got another PC to try something. I was able to redirect the video stream to another computer?

It's possible without any device to buy, and I found the software OBS Studio. It works, but take too many resources for my client.

Do you have any idea how to run this on his potato PC without taking 15% CPU ? (**NUT container**, and **RAW** for video in my parameters)

Comment: Any solution that would exist would take resources to implement.  Since you have to process the stream that is received.

Comment: "Maybe's" and questions not clarified don't give us a good idea what you're asking. Please clarify with your client the actual needs, requirements, and issues, do some research, and then if you still have questions ask them with the additional clarity you'll have then.

Comment: I don't know if this is the answer for your particular question but I'm guessing you need to use NDI.  If you haven't looked that up then it's worth investigating.  That allows your devices to talk to each other as NDi sources.